# Energy and force relation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, biology, displacement

So in simple machine we apple less force with more displacement to exert same energy as the load need so if energy is related to tiredness i.e. more energy you lose more tired you feel but by applying less force we didn't felt tired why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy used by your body and muscles is not the same as the work done on an object you manipulate.  The body takes more energy to do the work because it is an engine with less than 100% efficiency.  Also, being "out of breath" or feeling muscle fatigue is a complicated biological  response, and not a good measure of physical quantities like work.

The relationship between force $F$, displacement $d$ and work $W$ (in a straight line) is

$$ W=Fd $$

So you can apply a lower force for a longer distance and output the same work.